# Best way to generate many to many relationship in Excel 2007?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I need to store plant names and the properties they have. One plant may have many properties, and the same property may be held by more than one plant (many-to-many relationship). Both plant names and properties are simple string data.

Now I need to be able to search which plants hold a specific property, and also to search for a plant and view which properties are associated to it.

If this was a database I would make a table for properties, a second table for plants, and a third table with a foreign key for plants and one for properties. But then I'd need to build an application that allows me to search and view data easily. Is there a way to do the same with excel 2007? I just need simplicity and not to invest a long time (as I would if I had to build an app).

Thanks!

Comment: Look into the various methods of Lookups; VLookup, Index/Match, etc.

Comment: There is no easy way for that. You may find workaround,  but I can't tell you the "best way" as it depends on the size of your dataset,  complexity of actions you need ... Anyway,  I don't think using a tool which is not designed for the purpose you need would really be the best option you have.

Comment: You can use filter, just write your Data each in column(plants in A2 and each property in other column same row) and you can filter the Data as you wish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Excel doesn't do relationships like database tables, but it can be a very powerful tool for sorting and searching thru data.

Once your data is entered into Excel, [pivot tables](http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html) can allow you to filter and view specific results. [Microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576) describes it like this:

> PivotTables are a great way to summarize, analyze, explore, and
>   present your data, and you can create them with just a few clicks.
>   PivotTables are highly flexible and can be quickly adjusted depending
>   on how you need to display your results. You can also create
>   PivotCharts based on PivotTables that will automatically update when
>   your PivotTables do.